# how can wordpress `'FS_METHOD', 'direct';` identify wordpress administrators

Tags: php, wordpress

My wordpress have serval administrators. Now i want to make wordpress update automatically and use the following configure:

```
define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');
```

It works, but all the administrators have the permission to update or install wp plugins without password. I want just me have this permission, How can i do that?

Comment: Why do you want an administrator that should not administer the website? Can't you just adopt the Editor privilege? Thank you for this clarification

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to remove this capability of updating plugins from the administrator level, just leaving you as the Super Administrator, who is capable of doing this. Google more about Wordpress Role plugins which can alter these permissions or program the change yourself. Read more about removing capabilities here http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_cap

List of capabilities here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Capabilities

A very fast answer which you put in your functions.php file:

```
$wp_roles->remove_cap( 'administrator', 'edit_plugins' );
```